# copy constructor for derived class with linklist member

Tags: c++

I have been looking at examples of copy constructors for derived classes but I really don't understand how I'm supposed write this one.

I have three classes `LinkList`, `CD`, and `Media`.

I have written copy constructors for `Media` and `LinkList` but not `CD` which is a derived class of `Media` and has a `LinkList` for its member variable.

Please any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

```
class LinkList
{
  private:      
    struct ListNode
    {
      T value1;                
      struct ListNode *next;  
    }; 

    ListNode *head;   // List head pointer

  public:
    //***Constructor***
    LinkList();
    LinkList(const LinkList<T> &);
    //***Destructor***
    ~LinkList();

    //***LinkList Operations***
    //....operation functions
};      

//***Constructor***
template <class T>
LinkList<T>::LinkList()
{
    head = NULL;
}

//***Copy Constructor***
template <class T> 
LinkList<T>::LinkList( const LinkList &listObj )
{

    head = NULL;
    ListNode *nodePtr;
nodePtr = listObj.head;
    while(nodePtr != NULL)
    {
      appendNode(nodePtr->value1);
      nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
}
}

class Media
{
  private:

    string title;
    string length;

  public:       
    //***Constructors***
     Media();
     Media(string, string);
     Media(const Media &obj);
     //***destructor***
     ~Media();

     //***Mutators***
    void setTitle(string);
    void setLength(string);

    //***Accessors***
    string getTitle();
    string getLength();

    //Overloaded Operators

    bool operator < (const Media &);
    bool operator > (const Media &);
    bool operator != (const Media &);
    bool operator == (const Media &right);
 };

/*****Implimentation*********/
//***Constructors***
Media::Media()
{
title = "  ";
length = " ";
}

//***Constructors***
Media::Media(string t, string l)
{
title = t;
length = l;
}

//***Copy Constructor***
Media::Media(const Media &obj)
{
title = obj.title;
length = obj.length;
}

//LinkList structure for CD class

struct CdContence
{
string song;
string length;
};



class CD : public Media
{
public:

      LinkList<CdContence> Cd;

      //***Constructors***
      CD(string, string);
  CD();

      //***destructor***
      ~CD();

      //***Mutators***
      void setCD(string, string, string, string);

     //***Accessors***
     LinkList<CdContence> getCD();


     //Overloaded Operators

     bool operator < (CD &);
     bool operator > (CD &);
     bool operator != (CD &);
     bool operator == (CD &);
};

/*****Implimentation*********/
//***Constructors***
CD::CD(string T, string L)
{
 setTitle(T);
 setLength(L);
 LinkList<CdContence>Cd;

   cout<<"CD CONSTRUCTOR2"<<endl;
}

CD::CD() : Media()
{
LinkList<CdContence>Cd;

cout<<"CD CONSTRUCTOR"<<endl;
}

CD::CD(const CD &obj) :Media(obj)
{
//not sure what to put here since the member variable is 
// a linklist

}
```

Comment: You called the copy constryctor of parent class so you only need to copy your non dervied members. And since LinkedList has copy constructor you can do it with = operator. But be aware that you only copy pointers to nodes not nodes themselves (not sure if this is what you want to get)

Comment: Is there a reason why you are writing your own linked list instead of using a standard `std::list`?

Comment: kaman- thankyou I'm still working on the LinkList copy constructor.  I noticed that it wasn't copying the values assigned to the nodes but Im not sure how to fix that.  Any suggestions?

Comment: This is for a class I'm taking online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the solution provided below by @Remy Lebeau

```
CD::CD(const CD &obj) :Media(obj), Cd(obj.Cd) {}
```

Comment: You are invoking `Cd`'s assignment operator, not its copy constructor. To invoke the copy constructor, put `Cd(obj.Cd)` in the initialization list after `Media(obj)` instead: `CD::CD(const CD &obj) :Media(obj), Cd(obj.Cd) {}`

Comment: @RemyLebeau, yes you are right, I first had the impression that `Cd` was just created there...

Comment: Does that mean the copy constructors for Media and LinkList are wrong? Also do I need both the copy constructor and the assignment operator for each class?

Comment: You need assignment operator whenever, for example, you define an object `Foo A;`, then do something like `A=B`. If you declare `Foo A = B;`, then the copy constructor of `A` is invoked (whenever you create an object, its constructor is invoked; assignment operator is only invoked when both objects already exist). If your `Media` and `LinkList` copy constructors are OK, then `CD` copy constructor should work.

Comment: I'm writing these because Im passing a CD object into an append function for a LinkList that holds CD objects. The CD object is generated in a do-while loop. The program crashes during clean up because it has already freed the memory of the CD object when it leaves the loop and then tries to free it again.  I can post the code for that if you like.

Comment: Well I plugged that in and now the program freezes up after a few times through the loop. It  doesn't throw an error or exception.  Now I'm really confused.

Comment: Why do you declare `LinkList<CdContence>Cd;` in the `CD` constructors? You already defined it as a member variable, and in your code right now you are not doing anything with the other definition.